# adding html on toolbar

Tags: android, html, toolbar

hi I want to try a text on toolbar with insert link ı create string file 
and add this:
but there is seen with html tags. do not convert html to text. what can ı do?
thanks.

```
<string name="asd"><![CDATA[<h3 style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.xxxxxxx.com">go this page</a></h3>]]</string>


 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.asd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the closing `>` so try

```
<![CDATA[<h3 style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.xxxxxxx.com">
        go this page</a></h3>]]>
//                             ^
```

and use

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.asd)));
// create formatted string      ^^^^^^^^^^        |
// get string from string.xml                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @danyali i am glad that i could help, happy coding